# How to working with matrices using java

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

i have come up with a code to calculate the transpose of a matrix, but it seems to giving an error... any advice regarding improving the code would be helpful.

```
public class Prob1_Matrices {

    public static int[][] Transpose2D(int m[][]) {
       int B[][] = new int[m.length][m[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                int temp = B[i][j];
                B[i][j] = B[j][i]; // this is line 10
                B[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }
        return B;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m[][] = {{2, 5, 8, 3, 6},
        {4, 2, 9, 3, 1},
        {8, 0, 9, 5, 2}};
        System.out.println("Matrix:");
        System.out.println(Transpose2D(m)); //this is line 22
    }

}
```

Comment: its says exception at line 10 and 22.... i specify which ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B[i][j] = B[j][i];
B[j][i] = temp;
```

If your matrix is not square, this will possibly throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (if your array is for example 2x10 and you try `array[1][8] = array[8][1]`.) You probably meant it more like:

```
public static int[][] Transpose2D(int m[][]) {
   int B[][] = new int[m[0].length][m.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
            B[j][i] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**There are three problem in your code.**

Firstly you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because here:

`B[i][j] = B[j][i];`

you are trying to access non existing index in your array B.

Size of B should be declared as `int B[][] = new int[m[0].length][m.length];`as you want B matrix to be a transpose of m.

---

Secondly, you don't use the `m` array when you calculating B array. I also don't see why you use a temporary variable `int temp`, that should do what you need:

`B[j][i] = m[i][j];`

---

The third problem is that you here:
`System.out.println(Transpose2D(m));`
 you are trying to print array as it is. That will not work. Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Transpose2D(m)))
```

Answer (score 1):

B is the transpose Matrix, so maybe it should have the opposite size of m?

As m dimension are:

```
m.length * m[0].length
```

B should be:

```
m[0].length * m.length
```

a | b | c

d | e | f

shall be transpose to

a | d

b | e

c | f

Other problem is you don't use m in your function.
a correct use should be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            B[i][j] = m[j][i];
        }
    }
```

edit: swap i and j limit. thanks to David Wallace

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems - the first is that you've declared the wrong dimensions for `B`.  It should be `new int[m[0].length][m.length]`, not the other way around.

The second is that you are trying to copy entries from `B` back to itself, before creating any data for `B`.  So you're actually copying nothing.  The third problem - even if you had entries in `B`, you're swapping each pair of them twice, so this code would never have any effect.

You want to copy entries from `m` to `B` instead.  So in the loop, you want `B[j][i] = m[i][j];` instead of trying to swap entries within `B`.